# When using generics, how do I define a static instantiator of the generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, static

##### My goal (so that I don't run into an x-y problem):

I am trying to make a `Filter` class which works with a `T` generic type. Since the filter works Vector operations, I want to convert the object to a `Vector<double>`, do the filtering and then convert it back to `T` once the data is requested.

##### Interface cannot have static methods

I made an interface that should look something like this.

```cs
public interface IFilterable {

    public Vector<double> ToVector();
   
    public static IFilterable FromVector(Vector<double> vec);
}
```

So that I can use it over in the `Filter`:

```cs
public class Filter<T> where T: IFilterable {
    private Vector<double> _state;

    public T GetState() { 
        return T.FromVector(); 
    }
```

Interfaces cannot have static methods, so I'm looking for an alternative that gives me this behavior, that still allows me to use `T` as the generic type.

Comment: An abstract class allows you to define static methods without implementation

Comment: @404 good idea, though only works when the filterable derivative is not already extending a different class.

Comment: IDE tells me that "Non-abstract and non-extern method must declare a body", so I added a `throw new NotImplementedException()` for now.

Comment: @Speterius indeed, and in fact you can't make it abstract. You will need the 'new' keyword to override the static ToVector () operation in the derived class.

Comment: @Speterius the method itself also needs to be abstract to declare without body. Classes deriving from it should use `override` to implement them.

Comment: An additional thing I'm trying right now i where I keep the interface IFilterable but make the `FromVector` method non-static and cast to (T)

`return (T) (new T()).FromVector(_state);`

Comment: Not the worst of ideas, but you could avoid the cast by making the Interface generic. `interface IFilterable<T>` => `T FromVector(Vector<double>)` and `class SomeFilterableType : IFilterable<SomeFilterableType>` as well as `class Filter<T> where T: IFilterable<T>` - should work, no?

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mt06z3

Comment: I don't think you need to cast to T in the GetState method. T is already known to implement IFilterable, so just have GetState return an IFilterable rather than a T? So GetState would contain: 'return default (T).FromVector (_state);'

Comment: @muszeo I think the whole purpose of "IFilterable" is to have a type implement the required functionality to be used in a Filter. Outside the filter you want the type itself.

Comment: On second thought: If you managed to filter on a `Dictionary<double, T>` you could even avoid the creation of copies ... and with `Dictionary<T,double>` even duplicates in the double values would be possible ...

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: @Fildor It works using your code snippet. I added it as an answer for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Fildor for a solution with interfaces:

```
public interface IFilterable<out T> where T: new() {

    abstract Vector<double> ToVector();

    T FromVector(Vector<double> vec);
}
```

Which can be used by the `Filter` like this:

```
public class Filter<T> where T : IFilterable<T>, new() {
    
    private Vector<double> _state;
    
    public T GetState() {
        return new T().FromVector(_state);
    }
}
```

Additional solutions include using an abstract class instead of an interface.